# Submitting with Javascript and getting form data with php

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a search bar that uses a javascript function to submit the form when the user hits Enter (which is working) because it doesn't have a submit button, but I need to use php to handle the data in the textbox on post. The form is submitting, but on post it's not able to grab what was in the search textbox.

Here's the code:

```
<form id="siteWideSearch" name="siteSearch" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <input id="homeSearch" type="text" maxlength="100" onkeypress="startSiteSearch(event);" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {

    document.getElementById("siteWideSearch").submit();
}
```

PHP:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert(\"Post reached. Yay!!\");</script>";
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert(\"Search Criteria: ".trim($_POST['homeSearch'])."\");</script>";
}
```

I get the popup saying that post was reached, but the second popup just outputs "Search Criteria: " and nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the name attribute on your form input. Without it that value is not submitted.

```
<input id="homeSearch" type="text" maxlength="100" onkeypress="startSiteSearch(event);" />
```

should be:

```
<input name="homeSearch" id="homeSearch" type="text" maxlength="100" onkeypress="startSiteSearch(event);" />
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick lol. You're completely right, don't know how I midded that. Thank you so much! (been wrestling with this for a while now)